# when i select any ios device arm64 then app show this error

Tags: ios, archive, rosetta

when i run app on Rosetta mod it work in xcode . but when i select any ios device arm64 then app show this error
'/Users/Mrzee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeepSoundiOS-bxaogmncnnocxegvbkpfzfxmltrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/Mrzee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DeepSoundiOS-bxaogmncnnocxegvbkpfzfxmltrg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit' for architecture arm64

please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.